# SQL Server no statistics in sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats

Tags: sql-server, indexing, usage-statistics

This view used to show info about my databases, and a bunch of backup scripts were built using this information. Suddenly, this view has NOTHING from any database except MSDB. I did some work a few months back with clearing out all data and re-importing it from a different version on a different machine. Could this have something to do with it? How do I make this start keeping stats again?

Comment: Have you restarted the sql server service recently?

Comment: Yes, this server occasionally restarts itself for no reason that I have ever been able to determine. But the databases have been in use since the last such restart.

Comment: *"The counters are initialized to empty whenever the database engine is started. Use the sqlserver_start_time column in sys.dm_os_sys_info to find the last database engine startup time. In addition, whenever a database is detached or is shut down (for example, because AUTO_CLOSE is set to ON), all rows associated with the database are removed."* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-usage-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Thanks, I guess that was it. I thought it had last restarted a while back, but I looked at the index stats view again today and more stuff  is now in it, so I guess I missed a restart.